# How to append Spark ApplicationID in filename of log4j log file - Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

I am trying to append the Spark applicationId to the filename of log4j log file. Below is log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=info,file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -%m%n

# Redirect log messages to log file, support file rolling
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=log4j//Data_Quality.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L -%m%n

# set the immediate flush to true
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true

# set the threshold to debug mode INFO
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=INFO

#Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
```

Spark-submit command:

```
spark2-submit -conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=./input.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" --files "input.conf,log4j.properties" --master yarn --class "DataCheckImplementation" Data_quality.jar
```

Logfiles are created with name : Data_Quality.2020-07-21.log, which is working correctly.

I want to add Spark ApplicationID to filename
Expected filename :   Data_Quality.(ApplicationID).2020-07-21.log

Example: Data_Quality.(application_1595144411765_20000).2020-07-21.log

Is it possible? Need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know/think if this can be at configuration level (e.g lo4j.properties, etc), but there are ways we can achieve this. Here is one approach:

You will need to have a logger class/trait where you deal with all you logger management, something like :

```
trait SparkContextProvider {
 def spark: SparkSession
}

trait Logger extends SparkContextProvider {

lazy val log = Logger.getLogger(...)

lazy val applicationId = spark.sparkContext.applicationId

val appender = new RollingFileAppender();
        appender.setAppend(true);
        appender.setMaxFileSize("1MB");
        appender.setMaxBackupIndex(1);
        appender.setFile("Data_Quality" + applicationId + "_" + dateFormat.format(date) + ".log");
        appender.activateOptions();

        val layOut = new PatternLayout();
        layOut.setConversionPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n");
        appender.setLayout(layOut);

        log.addAppender(appender);
}
```